# How do I summarize means across columns, including a calculated column?

Tags: r, dplyr

How would I use the `dplyr` `summarize` function in order to calculate the mean across all columns, but include the results from a custom column that requires the raw data?

Here's an example using the `msleep` dataset.  I want the result to be one line showing the means, and the correct result for the `sleep_tot_rem` column that I created.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Incorrect calculation for Mutated Column
msleep %>% filter(!is.na(sleep_rem)) %>% mutate(sleep_tot_rem = sleep_total / sleep_rem) %>% 
  summarize_if(is.numeric, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake brainwt bodywt sleep_tot_rem
#>         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1        10.4      1.88       0.440  13.6   0.106   63.3          6.97

# Correct calculation for mutated column
msleep %>% filter(!is.na(sleep_rem)) %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, sum, na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(sleep_tot_rem = sleep_total / sleep_rem)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 7
#>   sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake brainwt bodywt sleep_tot_rem
#>         <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1        634.      114.        14.1  830.    5.11  3861.          5.54
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Move the `mutate` before `summarize_if`, to after `summarise_if`. This works because sum/sum is the same as mean/mean. The denominators cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first result *is* the correct calculation for the average ratio of total sleep to rem sleep. The average of a ratio is unlikely to be the same as the ratio of the average values. The question you need to answer is which you want: the average ratio or the ratio of the averages.

If the former, use your first calculation because you want to take the average of the calculated results. If the latter, use the second calculation because you want to calculate the results based on the average sleep. As long as both measures have the same number of entries, the ratio of the sums is equal to the ratios of the means (the sum is just the mean times the number of values -- a constant that cancels out on top and bottom).

We can see this in a simplified example. If we create two variables, `a` and `b`:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 11:20
```

We can see that the average ratio of a:b is:

```
mean(a / b)
```

0.3312286, while the ratio of the averages is:

```
mean(a) / mean(b)
```

0.3548387.

This has to do with differences in the weighting. The average of the ratios weights all 10 values the same, but the ratio of the averages is more impacted by any outlier values. This is even more obvious if you use a more extreme example:

```
x <- c(1:9, 100)
y <- c(2*(1:9), 500)

mean(x / y)
mean(x) / mean(y)
```

Here, the average ratio is 0.47 because the `100/500 = 0.2` has a relatively small impact. However, the ratio of the average is 0.2458 because 100 and 500 each have a much larger impact on the mean than the other 9 values.